# Error when "catkin_make" is run

Tags: ros, gazebo

I cloned a gazebo ROS package from https://github.com/YugAjmera/omni3ros_pkg and if I try to do **catkin_make**,I get the following error.
I am using Gazebo 11 and ROS Noetic and i've made sure to source the shell.
[image: error]

I am new to ROS and Gazebo. It will be helpful if someone help me resolve this, Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics*, Abhinandan K. There are two suggested solutions given in your screenshot. Did you try either of them? What happened?

Comment: run the command `rospack list` and check if you have gazebo items (ex: gazebo-dev, gazebo-msgs, etc...). What happens when you type `gazebo` into the terminal? does Gazebo start? At first blush it looks like you are missing Gazebo. How did you install ROS? I recommend the full-desktop-install.

Comment: @Mike Yes I have installed gazebo, it runs when I type gazebo in the terminal, gazebo runs when I run a different gazebo launch file from a different package, I might be missing something in the current package

Comment: @Chuck I did not know what to do for the solutions mentioned in the error, I'd be helpful if someone shed more light on that, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From the error screenshot you posted:

`Add the installation prefix of "gazebo" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "gazebo_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files. If "gazebo" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.`

Since [you said that you have gazebo installed](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/21336/error-when-catkin-make-is-run?noredirect=1#comment34990_21336), do you have the reference set in `gazebo_DIR`? Find what `gazebo_DIR` is currently set to, find where the `gazeboConfig.cmake` or `gazebo-config.cmake` files are located on your computer, and check that the two directories match.